# Display Values from wrapper class in apex controller

Tags: java, salesforce, apex-code, apex

This is my wrapper class,

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public class JSON2Apex {
        public List<Results> results;
        public String status;
    }

    public class Location {
        public Double lat;
        public Double lng;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

My apex controller is,

```
public class callout
{
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callout(String add,Id cntid)
    {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+add+'&key=AIzaSyDvf7W2SWXwUPXy8X2PSIGM6NwVusZywx4');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        if(res.getStatusCode()==200)
        {
            JSON2Apex2 obj = (JSON2Apex2 )JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), JSON2Apex2.class);
            System.debug('Here I want to diplay lat and lng values');
        }
    }
}
```

Here I want to display lat and lng values in location method in apex controller, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot because you have no instance of your inner class as a property of your outer class so it's not exposed as part of the class.  You need a property like currentLocation or something similar.

**Edited answer to update property name:**

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public Location location {get; set;}

    public class JSON2Apex {
         public List<Results> results;
         public String status;
    }

    public class Location {
        public Double lat;
        public Double lng;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

Then in your other code sample it would be

```
 System.debug('Here I want to diplay lat and lng values' + obj.location.lat + ' ' + obj.location.lng);
```

Comment: No,It show attempt to reference null object error.There is no value in currentlocation

Comment: WHat does your json response look like?

Comment: I dont know what your json looks like that why I said a property like current location or something similar.  But just doing a similar call, the property name would be "location" most likely. so I'll update the answer.